# Apache / PHP-FPM with dedicated error log file per host

Tags: php, apache

I'm running php7.2-fpm with apache 2.4.29 on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS.

I'm unable to set a specific php error log file per host (as I normally do with php with apache pre-fork).

On apache host conf file I set my custom error log path:

```
ErrorLog /var/www/server_logs/myhost_error.log
LogLevel warn
```

But that file is empty
Looking at /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf I saw that error log file is set to /var/log/php7.2-fpm.log and error level is enable and set to notice.

On my php project base path I put .user.ini containing

```
display_errors=on
display_startup_errors=on
error_reporting=E_ALL
html_errors=on
```

On my php project I generate a WARNING: I see it on screen but never get logged in my apache custom log error file nor in /var/log/php7.2-fpm.log

In /var/log/php7.2-fpm.log I only see

```
[17-Oct-2019 16:01:44] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 25328
[17-Oct-2019 16:01:44] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[17-Oct-2019 16:01:44] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

but no errors logged!

I cannot understand what I missed!

Anyone could help me please?

Comment: have you set the correct permissions for the error log? it should be accessible by the user/group defined in your apache config

Comment: Yes, I have them! If I delete the custom error log file and restart apache service file will be created correctly and report some notice of apache.

Comment: Can you see if it's being logged in the default error log file? Usually it's in /var/log/apache2

Comment: no, I guess you mean /var/log/apache2/error.log... no php errors there...

Comment: I found the file in /tmp/php_error_mysite.log ... found also that one of my scripts override that value :-(